# Microsoft Bot Framework - Adaptive cards not sending when dialog is stored in separate file

Tags: node.js, chatbot, azure-bot-service

**Bot Info**

- SDK Platform: Node.js
- SDK Version: 8.11.2
- Active Channels: Bot Framework Emulator and Direct Line
- Deployment Environment: Local development with Emulator

**Issue Description**

I have created a separate file that contains a bot dialog. In my index.js, I import the module and call the dialog in the proper place. When it comes about sending normal text it works just fine.

However, when I am sending an adaptive card, which works when the entire code is placed in the index.js file, the bot emulator crashes and turns all black. I also tried the direct line locally and the result is that it indefinitely shows the "is typing icon", which happens to be right before the call that is supposed to send the message.

**Reproduction Steps**

You can follow this basic example to test the issue:

```
module.exports = function(bot) { 
    bot.dialog('pcnLogin', [
      function (session, args) {
         let msg = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(yourCard);
         session.send(msg);
      }]);
}
```

Then, import the module in the main file:

```
require('./dialogs')(bot);
```

Finally, call the dialog from the main bot flow:

```
session.beginDialog('pcnLogin');
```

**Final Comments**

I do not get any error in the console. The only behaviors are:

- emulator crashing and turning black
- infinite ellipsis when tested in an HTML file

I would like to stress that the exact same code works perfectly if it is included in the index.js.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed! The adaptive card object I was passing in the attachment had an undefined value due to a wrong import! :)